# Compilation error - Array index is past the end of array blah.groupsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO] = ToTrace[number];

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO  3

struct blahS
{
    unsigned int groupsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO];
} blahS;

int main()
{
   //Value hardcoded to 7 just for testing purpose. Otherwise value is assigned from another function
    signed int trace = 7; //trace reads value of range [0-7] from a function

    unsigned int ToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO];
    unsigned int number = 0;
    unsigned int noOfGroups = 100;

    if (trace != 0)
    {
      if ((trace == 1)) //b'001
      {
        ToTrace[number] = noOfGroups / 8;
        number++;
      }
      if ((trace == 4)) //b'100
      {
        ToTrace[number] = noOfGroups / 2;
        number++;
      }
      if ((trace == 7)) //b'111
      {
        ToTrace[number] = noOfGroups * 7 / 8;
        number++;
      }
    }
    struct blahS blah;
    blah.groupsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO] = ToTrace[number]; //Compilation-error
    
    return 0;
}
```

Basically this is an if-loop which checks and decides groupToTrace based on bit-mapping for a trace value allocated. At the last line i got a compilation error saying - Array index 3 is past the end of the array. I am assigning the calculated groupToTrace values to newPointer_p->groupsToTrace[3] where groupsToTrace[3] is stored in a struct

**Question** is I got a compilation error as mentioned above with out of bounds access to the array as i understand. But i don't understand where is the mistake.

Compiler version gcc.x86_64 4.8.5-39.el7 @GSS-RHEL7

Any clues or hints highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you create an array of size `3`, it's valid indices are `0`, `1`, and `2`.  As the error says, `blah.groupsToTrace[3]` is past the end.

Comment: Can't reproduce on same version of gcc.  How exactly are you compiling?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue either on onlinegdb compiler. 
But i see compilation error at my work space. I was still wondering how is it possible.
When i read the code i can sense there is something going out of bound for the array. I got no clue for this. 
@0x5453 You are right there. Any hint on how to assign ToTrace[number] value to blah.groupsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what this line is doing:

```
blah.groupsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO] = ToTrace[number];
```

This is not copying the entire contents of one array to another.  It is copying index `number` of `ToTrace` to index `LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO` of `blah.groupsToTrace`.  Both of these indices have the value 3 which is out of bounds for both arrays, as an array of size 3 has indices 0, 1, and 2.

You either need a loop to copy the elements:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<number; i++) {
    blah.groupsToTrace[i] = ToTrace[i];
}
```

Or you could use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(blah.groupsToTrace, ToTrace, sizeof(blah.groupsToTrace));
```

Comment: Ok. I think i totally carried away. 
The for loop is classical way of explaining the index to index copy method. 
But i will choose memcpy because of less time for compilation. 
Thanks for the great input mate!